# how to present function name at statusline on vim

Tags: vim

When I open any .c file, I hope that function name will be present at statusline according to current cursor position.

```
set statusline=%<%F%h%m%r%h%w%y\ %{strftime(\"%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M\")}%=\ col:%c%V\ ascii:%b\ pos:%o\ lin:%l\,%L\ %P
```

plz let me know how to present function name at statusline on vim

Comment: Your sample is a pretty regular status line and it is irrelevant to the problem at hand. Did you consider the fact that you actually have two problems, here? Problem #1 is "how to get the name of the current function" and problem #2 is "how to display some arbitrary information in my status line". What did you actually try to address problem #1? Problem #2?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the solution.

first, it need to ctag. and then below vim.tgz extract at home directory.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e5_j79GILRrUr4rn6W9OsQAvnR-7n0Ao/view?usp=sharing

thanks
Bryan

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Asking people to download a file from an untrusted source and extract it on their machine is a non-starter.